# How do I create reusable template parts in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component with a few blocks that repeat throughout the template. These blocks may have a conditional or two and might call some methods in event handlers, but mostly they're pretty simple.

It is really not worth creating an entire, separate component for a few elements, plus passing around data and methods isn't exactly trivial, making the component more difficult to maintain. So these blocks won't be used in any other components.

I really need to be able to define a *"subcomponent"* or *"template"* inside this component for these blocks. I don't know if this is possible yet. Has anyone figured out a clean solution for this?

Comment: https://vueuse.org/core/createReusableTemplate/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Components can be defined as *render functions*, and this is especially easy with [JSX](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#jsx):

```js
const ComponentA = props => (
  <div>
    <label>{props.label} <input type="text" /></label>
  </div>
)
```

You could declare multiple subcomponents as render functions (or full component definition objects if needed) in the same file, and reuse them in the component's template. Vue 3's `<script setup>` block also helps to make this more concise:

```html
<script lang="jsx" setup>
const SubComponentA = (props) => (
    <div>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input type="number" />
    </div>
)
const SubComponentB = (props) => (
    <div>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <textarea />
    </div>
)
</script>

<template>
  <SubComponentA label="Label 1" />
  <SubComponentB label="Label 2" />
  <SubComponentA label="Label 3" />
  <SubComponentB label="Label 4" />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-quick-subcomponents?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: What does the scope look like for these? Does it only operate with what's passed to it like a normal component or does it have access to the parent component context?

Comment: In `<script setup>`, the subcomponents *can* have access to the parent component context ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-quick-subcomponents-ti4xrv?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)).